# Referencing directories within an Xcode project for an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, file, mainbundle

I need to be able to reference specific files within a directory inside of my xCode project. So far I have this code:

```
let files = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sampleFile", ofType: "csv")
var contents = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
```

Which works to open a single file, but I would like to be able to open a file that is stored inside one or two directories within the main bundle.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of NSBundle to specify the directory for a single file

```
  let file = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sampleFile", ofType: "png", inDirectory:"Images")
```

or for multiple files of the same type

```
  let files = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResourcesOfType("png", inDirectory:"Images")
```